# Taylor formula with integral remainder in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $V\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$

How to write the Taylor formula with integral remainder of order $n$ for the gradient of $V$ in some element $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

Thanks

Comment: Look at $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $g(t)=V(x_0+th)$.

Comment: @ user10354138, i don't see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Apply the 1-dimensional version of Taylor's theorem to the real-variable function $g(t)=V(x_0 + th)$ at $0$, i.e.,

$$g(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)t^k}{k!} + o(t^n)$$
which implies
$$V(x_0 + th)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\nabla^{(k)}V(x_0)h^k}{k!} + o(t^n)$$
where $h^k$ = $(h, h, ..., h) \in (\mathbb{R}^d)^k$.